# How to re-map the fields of a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

Picture it -- I have a collection, and it has a particular mapping.

Pretend:

```
{
    "field": "lala", 
    "subdoc": {
        "otherfield": "la", 
        "etcfield": "la"
    }
}
```

And I need to convert that to a different data structure:

```
{
    "field-gets-renamed": "lala", 
    "subdoc-has-different-stuff-in-it": {
        "something": "la", 
        "something-else": "la"
    }
}
```

What is the typical way of doing that?  (Is there one?)

Do I read collection1 doc by doc and write it to a different collection?
Or is there a way to just remap the fields in collection1?

I would greatly appreciate some example, as I am a novice to mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the [$rename operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#_S_rename)

In your case it would be:

```
db.collectionName.update({}, { $rename : { 'field' : 'field123',  'subdoc' : 'subdoc123', 'subdoc.otherfield' : 'subdoc.otherfield123', 'subdoc.etcfield' : 'subdoc.etcfield123'} }, false, true);
```

*P.S: I havent tested the above command.*

Comment: Oh!  I get it :)  Thanks a lot.  And your command works well.